# PHONEGAP ANDROID: Hide Status Bar only on the Application Home Screen (SplashScreen)

Tags: android, cordova, splash-screen, statusbar, phonegap

I already used all the features I found here, but I could not change the black color of the status bar of my application in Phonegap.

I was able to change the color of the application's bar status using the plugin:

```
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" source="npm" />
<preference name="fullscreen" value="false" />
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16" />     
<preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="false" />   
<preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="false" />
<preference name="StatusBarBackgroundColor" value="#9d0101" />
<preference name="StatusBarStyle" value="lightcontent" /> 
<preference name="StatusBarDefaultScrollToTop" value="false" />
```

The application status bar changes the color as I want, however the Splashscreen keeps the color black and does not change, when I put "fullscreen" it adds, but I do not want my application in fullscreen, I would like to hide the status bar only on the Splash Screen. My app is compiled in Phonegap, how do I HIDE the Status Bar on SplashScreen only?

I've tried using the code below, but it leaves the whole app on fullscreen:

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
    <widget ... xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    ...
    <edit-config file="AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge"
                 target="/manifest/application/activity">
        <activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
    </edit-config>
    ...
</widget>
```

What I want is to hide the status bar only on the application launch screen, after that, it reappears according to the color I used.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add [Android Fullscreen](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/android-full-screen), and then the following configuration

config.xml

```
<edit-config file="AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application/activity">
    <activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar.Fullscreen" />
</edit-config>
```

app.component.ts

```
constructor(
    platform: Platform,
    statusBar: StatusBar,
    splashScreen: SplashScreen
    androidFullScreen: AndroidFullScreen
  ) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {
      splashScreen.hide();

      if (platform.is('android')) {
        androidFullScreen.showSystemUI();
      }

      statusBar.styleDefault();
    });
}
```